# ImportError: No module named 'Blender'

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to Blender scripting (and to python too), I started to try to use it but I already get some error...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named 'Blender'

This is my script...

```
import Blender
```

I know this sounds ridiculous, but I cannot find the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are following a tutorial/code written for Blender 2.49 or lower. However, if you are running that code in a current version of Blender 2.50 and upwards there is no module named `Blender`. That's why you get that Import Error.

A good place to get information about the current API and Blender script writing in general is the [current documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/). It contains :

- Blender/Python Quickstart: new to blender/scripting and want to get your feet wet?
- Blender/Python API Overview: a more complete explanation of python integration
- Blender/Python Addon Tutorial: a step by step guide on how to write an addon from scratch
- Blender/Python API Reference Usage: examples of how to use the API reference docs
- Best Practice: Conventions to follow for writing good scripts
- Tips and Tricks: Hints to help you while writing scripts for blender
- Gotcha’s: some of the problems you may come up against when writing scripts

...and a whole lot more :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm running on Blender 2.76, so I'm sure it will be useful. Let's dig into that!